# Dynamically determining if a collection path exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might seem like an unusual case.

If I am dynamically given a "@model" variable, that can be any ActiveRecord model class, how can I check if that model has a corresponding "/models" route?

Sometimes a model is a shallow resource inside another resource... meaning it never has a "/models" path on its own, so the url_helper for that wont exist.

I could do this but it sucks!

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.methods.include? "#{@model.to_s.pluralize.downcase}_path"
```

Comment: Are you using STI? Or why is it that your model object can be typed all or none?

Comment: The code I'm looking at uses a DRY controller. Which works fine, but in some places there is too much voodoo going on. hoping there is a simpler way to detect a route for a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to separate the simple resources from the nested resources. Then you only have to deal with one kind of route (simple routes). Inherit your controllers from an Admin::Base controller like:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  # abstracted admin logic
end

class Admin::PeopleController < Admin::BaseController
end
class Admin::CategoriesController < Admin::BaseController
end
```

and in the view use polymorphic pathes like:

```
<%= link_to 'all', @model_object.class.name.underscore.pluralize %>
<%= link_to 'show', @model_object %>
<%= link_to 'new', [:new, @model_object] %>
<%= link_to 'edit', [:edit, @model_object] %>
<%= link_to 'delete', @model_object, method: :delete %>
<%= form_for @model_object do |f| %>
  <!--Create or Update form for model object-->
<% end %>
```

Also read about polymorphic routes: [Simple RESTful Ruby on Rails routes](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/03/a-simple-ruby-on-rails-route.html).
If possible I'd use existing Admin gems like [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) or [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). Oftentimes they are sufficient.